# Run function whenever a change is made in database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to run a function whenever a change is made in the database.

Is there a way to avoid 3 loops to do so ? Here is my code:

```
    public void Save()
    {
        System.Data.Linq.ChangeSet changeSet = db.GetChangeSet();

        foreach (User user in changeSet.Inserts)
        {
            this.doSomeStuff();
        }

        foreach (User user in changeSet.Updates)
        {
            this.doSomeStuff();
        }

        foreach (User user in changeSet.Deletes)
        {
            this.doSomeStuff();
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: changeSet.Inserts.Concat(changeSets.Updates).Concat(changeSets.Deletes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "converting" @adrianm comment into an answer:

```
foreach (User user in changeSet.Inserts.Concat(changeSet.Updates).Concat(changeSet.Deletes) 
{
    this.doSomeStuff();
}
```